# Saving Array to separate columns in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684094 [amount] => 0.22 [country_code] => IN [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719614 [offer_id] => d067d8 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684093 [amount] => 2.00 [country_code] => CA [vertical] => casino [lead_time] => 1490719614 [offer_id] => dd94e1 [os_name] => iOS [browser] => Safari Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684092 [amount] => 0.02 [country_code] => IN [vertical] => dlpinsubmits [lead_time] => 1490719614 [offer_id] => 6346d4 [os_name] => Android [browser] => UCWeb [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684091 [amount] => 1.37 [country_code] => US [vertical] => appsdl [lead_time] => 1490719613 [offer_id] => b72f5b [os_name] => iOS [browser] => Safari Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684090 [amount] => 1.57 [country_code] => SA [vertical] => desktop [lead_time] => 1490719613 [offer_id] => f2cd6c [os_name] => Windows-Desktop [browser] => Chrome [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684089 [amount] => 2.00 [country_code] => US [vertical] => appsdl [lead_time] => 1490719613 [offer_id] => 4a7be3 [os_name] => iOS [browser] => Safari Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684088 [amount] => 0.16 [country_code] => KR [vertical] => directlink [lead_time] => 1490719613 [offer_id] => 71d97a [os_name] => Android [browser] => Android Webkit [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [7] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684087 [amount] => 0.06 [country_code] => LK [vertical] => appsdl [lead_time] => 1490719612 [offer_id] => 80d523 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [8] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684086 [amount] => 0.06 [country_code] => BD [vertical] => global [lead_time] => 1490719612 [offer_id] => dc8f47 [os_name] => Windows [browser] => IEMobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [9] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684085 [amount] => 0.38 [country_code] => TH [vertical] => appsaggressive [lead_time] => 1490719612 [offer_id] => 37d0ba [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [10] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684084 [amount] => 0.10 [country_code] => IN [vertical] => dlpinsubmits [lead_time] => 1490719611 [offer_id] => fb0389 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [11] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684083 [amount] => 0.10 [country_code] => AR [vertical] => appsaggressive [lead_time] => 1490719611 [offer_id] => 053900 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chromium [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [12] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684082 [amount] => 0.42 [country_code] => TH [vertical] => adultcontent [lead_time] => 1490719611 [offer_id] => 9cc4dd [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [13] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684081 [amount] => 0.02 [country_code] => BD [vertical] => directlink [lead_time] => 1490719610 [offer_id] => 7e1ea7 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [14] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684080 [amount] => 1.30 [country_code] => US [vertical] => dlpinsubmits [lead_time] => 1490719609 [offer_id] => 6dc0a5 [os_name] => iOS [browser] => Safari Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [15] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684079 [amount] => 0.14 [country_code] => BR [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719609 [offer_id] => 67bca5 [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [16] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684078 [amount] => 0.44 [country_code] => TR [vertical] => appsdl [lead_time] => 1490719609 [offer_id] => 9b2a2f [os_name] => iOS [browser] => Safari Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [17] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684077 [amount] => 0.20 [country_code] => HN [vertical] => global [lead_time] => 1490719609 [offer_id] => 3f476c [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [18] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684076 [amount] => 0.14 [country_code] => BR [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719609 [offer_id] => 0e1a7d [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [19] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684075 [amount] => 0.14 [country_code] => BR [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719608 [offer_id] => 0e1a7d [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [20] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684074 [amount] => 0.12 [country_code] => IN [vertical] => global [lead_time] => 1490719608 [offer_id] => 80957e [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [21] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684073 [amount] => 0.14 [country_code] => BR [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719608 [offer_id] => 0e1a7d [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [22] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684072 [amount] => 0.09 [country_code] => IR [vertical] => directlink [lead_time] => 1490719608 [offer_id] => addc2a [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 ) [23] => Array ( [lead_id] => 140684071 [amount] => 0.14 [country_code] => BR [vertical] => apps [lead_time] => 1490719607 [offer_id] => 0e1a7d [os_name] => Android [browser] => Chrome Mobile [is_omega] => 0 [is_vauto] => 1 )
```

Im needing to take this array an store it into MySQL. Seprating it out into ech column. So a Column lead_id an it would store the lead_id in there. Then Amount an So on. I need to loop the Array an do that for every value. How would I go about doing this? Ive tried multiple solutions people have stated online but none of them work for me. Thanks!

EDIT: I tried this

```
    /* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO liveleads (lead_id, amount, country_code, vertical, lead_time, offer_id, os_name, browser, is_omega, is_vauto) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $jsonArray['lead_id'], $jsonArray['amount'], $jsonArray['country_code'], $jsonArray['vertical'], $jsonArray['lead_time'], $jsonArray['offer_id'], $jsonArray['os_name'], $jsonArray['browser'], $jsonArray['is_omega'], $jsonArray['is_vauto']);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty basic task to loop over the array and run your SQL statements for each iteration. Or you could even get fancy and run them in batch with a stored procedure.

Comment: Something like `foreach($rows as $row){ foreach($row as $column => $value) {`

Comment: it helps if you also show us what you tried and didn't work as well as what the intended behaviour should have been. More often than not solutions you may give up on will actually work with little modification.

Comment: Added what I tried, fairly new with php. So trying to figure this out